# Want to set Slidervalue to a UserDefault: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type, uislider, userdefaults

My problem is that I want to set the value of a slider to a UserDefault. In the first version of the app everything worked fine and I use the same code in version 2. Now Xcode shows the error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value", but I never have used Optionals in the code. I have updated Xcode, maybe there is a problem.

Thank you in advance

```
func speichernNutzerEinstellungenIntervall(){
        standard.set(zeitInsgesamt, forKey: Keys.speichernZeitInsgesamt)
    }

func überprüfenLängeIntervall(){
    let speichernZeitInsgesamt = standard.integer(forKey: Keys.speichernZeitInsgesamt)

    zeitInsgesamt = speichernZeitInsgesamt 

    sliderIntervallOutlet.setValue(Float(zeitInsgesamt), animated: true) //Here I get the error}
```

(I have declared the variable "zeitInsgesamt" as a global variable. Don't know  if this is important.)

Comment: What is data type of zeitInsgesamt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `sliderIntervallOutlet` is `nil`. Try to check nil value for property before set any value. Like this

```
func überprüfenLängeIntervall(){
    let speichernZeitInsgesamt = standard.integer(forKey: Keys.speichernZeitInsgesamt)

    zeitInsgesamt = speichernZeitInsgesamt 

    if sliderIntervallOutlet != nil {
          sliderIntervallOutlet.setValue(Float(zeitInsgesamt), animated: true)
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get the Error: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int' " in the line with "if let speichernZeitInsgedamt....". Do you know how to fix that? I can't change speichernZeitInsgesamt to an optional, can I?

Comment: What is the value of `standard.integer(forKey: Keys.speichernZeitInsgesamt)`? is it returning any value?

Comment: Yes, I print it and it says "163". But when I want to set the value of the slider to the value of speichernZeitInsgesamt I get the error.

Comment: What is `sliderIntervallOutlet`? please check this is nil or not.

Comment: Yes, the value of sliderIntervallOutlet is nil. But why is that a problem?

Comment: sliderIntervallOutlet is not initialise or before initialization you try to put value on this. Or you can check the property is connected with Storyboard or not.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it with an if-statment: if sliderIntervallOutlet != nil. By the second the start of the app the slider value was set to the Userdefault-value.